# Azure Service Bus para Java

Tags: java, azure

tengo que programar un cliente de un broker Azure Service Bus, en Java. El problema que me surge es que me da este error al mismo arrancar la aplicación:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

y no tengo ni idea de por qué. Y la línea de código que da error es:

```
>     Configuration config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(Endpoint,SharedAccessKeyName,SharedAccessKey,".servicebus.windows.net");
>     service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
```

Para desarrollarlo estoy partiendo del ejemplo de Microsoft que se puede encontrar aquí: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-chat-for-java

He cogido todas las librerías de azure que vienen en el POM.xml (todas las que hay bajo la frase "Azure Java SDK libraries"): https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-chat-for-java/blob/master/azchat-web/pom.xml

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando? La documentación para de Microsoft sobre Azure Service Bus para Java deja bastante que desear :(

¿Puede ser problema de las versiones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado el error es que te falta la libreria de apache que contiene esa clase. Añadiendo esto al POM debería de funcionar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Espero te funcione, un saludo!

Comment: El problema al final era que, aun teniendo esta librería en el POM, la versión no era la adecuada. Actualizando la versión, funcionó. Gracias!!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro! Un saludo!